# Complicated polymorphic association query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, associations

I have a `Review` model and a `CheckIn` model:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :check_in, -> { where( reviews: { reviewable_type: "CheckIn"} ).includes(:review) }, foreign_key: 'reviewable_id', optional: true   
end

class CheckIn < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :review, as: :reviewable
end
```

And would like to be able to pull in all `:reviews` for `:check_ins` within a date range.  For example:

```
Review.includes(:check_in).where("check_ins.created_at >= ?", Date.today)
```

This fails due to:

> `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "check_ins"`

Is there some way to accomplish this?  Ideally I'd like an `ActiveRecord::Relation` and not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just have to let `ActiveRecord` know you're planning to query against `check_ins` table (AR knows it if the where clause looks like `check_ins: { anything }`, i.e. it's a `Hash`, but doesn't know it if it's `String`, like here), so it did `left join`, like this:

```
Review.includes(:check_in).references(:check_ins).where('check_ins.created_at >= ?', Date.today)
```

or with `eager_load`:

```
Review.eager_load(:check_in).where('check_ins.created_at >= ?', Date.today)
```

Also, if you're using Ruby 2.6, it might be possible to use infinite range, but I'm not sure it works (though I would be glad if it was, it looks cool :)):

```
Review.includes(:check_in).where(check_ins: Date.today..)
```